# Why is this if-statement true? Different arry address

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement

I don't understand why this if-statement is true can someone explain it to me?

```
int a[8][8] = {0};

if(&a[7][0] == &a[0][0] || &a[5][1])
    printf("true\n");
```

Comment: Is `(&a[7][0] == &a[0][0] || &a[5][1])` supposed to be `((&a[7][0] == &a[0][0]) || (&a[7][0] == &a[5][1]))`?

Comment: `&a[5][1]` is not `NULL`, so `if(....  || &a[5][1])` is true.

Comment: The expression `&a[7][0] == &a[0][0] || &a[5][1]` is the same as `(&a[7][0] == &a[0][0]) || (&a[5][1] != 0)`.

Comment: Zael, Curious: Why do you expect `&a[7][0] == &a[0][0] || &a[5][1]` to ever be false?

Comment: Because the address of the array element are different

Comment: That only applies to the first part of the conditional. Remember that `||` is a logical "or"...

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the way the `||` operator works.  It is not applied to each of the terms after an equality.  You seem to hope that writing `(a == b || c || d)` would be equivalent to `(a == b || a == c || a == d)`, but that is not how `||` works in C.  It works as `(a == b || c != 0 || d != 0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This conditional

```
if (&a[7][0] == &a[0][0] || &a[5][1])
```

means

```
if ( (&a[7][0] == &a[0][0]) || (&a[5][1] != 0) )
```

And in all cases, you will never find the address of `a[5][1]` to be zero. So your conditions are always met.

You probably had this condition in mind:

```
if (&a[7][0] == &a[0][0] || &a[7][0] == &a[5][1])
```